# How to build up the friend list?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I like to play Pokémon at competitive online play. Though singleplaying may have many key events for competitive playing. (Like the Mega stones, TMs, etc.)

Per passengers/friends you can receive additional advantages, such as O-Powers. So if you care about your friend list, it's more likely to receive these powers.

But then I'll have to ask myself: **Is it better to look for as many random and foreign friends as possible or to just keep local friends in the list?**

I will not have many local friends, as I'm too old for this shizzle, but I understand that they may give more powers, as we know each other. Foreign people may share a power once in a time, but as they will have other random friends it's not likely that I'm the one who receives it. On the other hand - the more foreigners I've got, my chances increases.

Comment: Side note, Everyone on Arqade is welcome to join us in the Pokémon chat room, [Kalos](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11030/kalos).

Comment: Never been to a chat room. I'll look up to it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say add as many people as possible, for a few reasons:

- **Friend Safari** - Each friend you have gives you another 'Safari' to go on. As you say you're interested in online multiplayer, Friend Safari is where you'll be able to find Pokemon with their Hidden Abilities, as well as starting out with two (or more!) max IV stats, making breeding that perfect Pokemon even easier.
- **O-Powers** - As you mention, you can receive O-Powers from friends. I've found it beneficial if I send a friend a 'Nice!' To draw attention, and changing my description to the O-power I need. Usually I'll receive it.
- **Fairly Risk free** - unlike other online chat/friending communities, Nintendo limits the amount of interaction friends can have with each other, usually leaving it to the individual games to implement chat, trade and other functions. Plus, in order for players to become friends, you must BOTH add each other, so even if someone gets your Friend code, you need theirs in order to become friends.
- **Easier trading** - You might spend hours if not days hunting for even the most trivial Pokémon on GTS. By befriending some people online, you may be able to request a trade, and come to an agreeable offer before ever hitting the trade button - saving you time and energy.

Obviously be vigilant, remember that some people can be scammers so make sure you're still wearing your common sense hat - but generally if you treat others well they will reciprocate.

Comment: Well ok, that convinces me. Do they have to be "Friends" or "Known-ones"? (Don't know the last noun as I don't play in English)

Comment: For friend Safari - you need to be friends, not just 'acquaintances' :-)